# Can not center image using asp.net and CSS (C#)

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am using the below code to center the image on my page. However the image remains stuck on the lefter side of the page.

I used the same technique on a login form, and it works.

`<asp:Image CssStyle="alignCenter" ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/resources/logo.gif" />`

```
.loginbox
{
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.alignCenter
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `img` is an inline element. To use the method you are trying to you should change it to a `block` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:Image CssClass="alignCenter" ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/resources/logo.gif" />
```

"CssClass" is correct attribute name.

Comment: your attribute name for specifying a css class was incorrect. For specifying a css class for an element you need to use CssClass attribute.